# Distinguish request from main window or popup window in struts action class

Tags: javascript, popup, struts

We have a regular struts based web application which opens pop up when clicked on specific 
links.
Certain links on main windows and popup window calls the same struts action class. Is there a way to identify in the action class whether that request has originated from main window or popup window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you provide some sort of unique token/link/cookie/etc. specific to the popup. It  looks like any other browser request--because it's like any other browser request.

(On a site-related note, your accept rating is pretty low--you can always go back and accept previous answers when they're correct, even though they're old.)

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag parameter while calling the action

**main window**

```
<a href="myAction?fromMain=true">link</a>
```

**pop-up window**

```
<a href="myAction?fromMain=false">link</a>
```

Now declare the boolean variable `fromMain` in `myAction` with getters to chek where the request is coming from.

Comment: i wish i could this, but problem is the webpages (main and popup) has too many links, to add the complexity we even have buttons where parent and child call the same javascript function when clicked.

Comment: you can add css class to those links and add the parameter dynamically using javascript/jquery checking the css class. For the buttons calling same javascript function you can pass different arguement to the functions depending on from which window they are being called